# How many and which values can/should be unitless in CSS

Tags: css

I know two

- margin {0 auto}
- line-height: 1.5;

is there any other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really have an answer for your question, but I just wanted to say that I don't think you should ever leave off the units unless you're specifying a value of 0. It's easier to read and there's no guesswork (for both the browser and someone else who may be reading your CSS).

**EDIT**: Pulled this from a forum. They are the CSS properties that accept integer values for [CSS 2.1 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html):

- z-index
- font-weight
- line-height
- counter-reset
- counter-increment
- volume
- stress
- pitch-range
- richness

Comment: but many css typography best practices prefer line-height unit-less like here for example http://21picas.co.uk/?p=364

Comment: @Jitendra - `line-height: 1.5` means 1.5 times the font-size; it's a special unit for line-height, different in meaning from 150%, but similar to `1.5em`

Comment: Unitless values for line-height are also inherited differently than ems or percent.  With a unit specified, the *calculated* value is inherited, whereas with unitless, the raw number value is inherited & recalculated for each child.

Comment: You'd think this would be CSS 101 (or maybe 201) but I've been doing this for many years and only just now learned about the differences in % vs em vs unitless line-height values. Here's Eric Meyer describing the issue waaaay back in 2006:   
http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/   
  
Here's a codepen that shows things more visually:   
http://codepen.io/JeffreyPia/pen/XKprWq

Answer (score 9):

The currently selected answer is out-of-date, and also misses a few of the ones in the CSS2 spec linked. As I needed a more up-to-date answer, here's a brief summary of what I've found.

Note that this is a list of which properties *can* be unitless, but not always necessarily *should* be. Also note obviously that any property which can accept a `'length'` value can therefore accept the unitless value of `0`.

This lists all CSS3 properties that accept numeric values (**[i]**nteger or **[f]**loat):

- animation-iteration-count (i)
- border-image-slice (f)
- border-image-width (f)
- column-count (i)
- counter-increment (i)
- counter-reset (i)
- flex (i)
- flex-grow (i)
- flex-shrink (i)
- font-size-adjust (f)
- font-weight (i)
- line-height (f)
- nav-index (i)
- opacity (f)
- order (i)
- orphans (i)
- tab-size (i)
- widows (i)
- z-index (i)

In addition to this list, the CSS2 specification also exclusively includes:

- pitch-range (f)
- richness (f)
- speech-rate (f)
- stress (f)
- volume (f)

And besides these, there are technically a few obscure ones (related to SVGs):

- flood-opacity (f)
- mask-box-outset / mask-border-outset (f)
- mask-box-width / mask-border-width (f)
- shape-image-threshold (f)

And, FTW, this seems to be a good reference of [all properties that ever existed](https://meiert.com/en/indices/css-properties/).

Answer (score 1):

Every numerical value other than 0 should have a unit.

```
margin:0; //Good
margin:15; //Bad.  Do you want px, em, %, etc?
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure I have had instances where leaving the value type off lead to display problems in other browsers. This is because they default to different types.
0 is 0 in any type.
Where 5px (pixels) can be a lot different then 5em (Width of the Current Fonts capital letter M).
As a best practice I say always use them. It's only a few more bytes of bandwidth.